# Обработка в stream объектов разных типов, имеющих общего родителя

Tags: java, наследование, потоки-данных

Имеется класс

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Type type;
    private int age;
    private Gender gender;

 // конструктор, сеттеры и геттеры

    public enum Type {PROFESSOR, STUDENT}
    public enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE}
}
```

и два дочерних класса

```
public class Teacher extends Person {
    private List<String> subjects;
    private List<String> groups;

    // для примера
    public List<String> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

// конструктор, сеттеры и остальные геттеры

}

public class Student extends Person {
    private String group;
    private int course;
    private List<String> subjects;

// конструктор, сеттеры и геттеры

}
```

В классе `University` формирую `ArrayList()`:

```
public class University {
    public static List<Person> people = List.of(
        new Teacher("Иванов", Person.Type.PROFESSOR, 52, Person.Gender.MALE,
            List.of("Математика", "Физика", "Химия"),
            List.of("Группа 1/2020", "Группа 2/2020", "Группа 3/2020")),
        new Teacher("Петрова", Person.Type.PROFESSOR, 42, Person.Gender.FEMALE,
            List.of("История"),
            List.of("Группа 1/2020", "Группа 2/2020", "Группа 3/2020")),
        new Teacher("Сидоров", Person.Type.PROFESSOR, 32, Person.Gender.MALE,
            List.of("Программирование на Java", "Основы программирования"),
            List.of("Группа 1/2021", "Группа 2/2021", "Группа 3/2021")),
        
        new Student("Медведев", Person.Type.STUDENT, 17, Person.Gender.MALE,
            "Группа 1/2021", 1, List.of("Математика", "Физика", "Химия")),
        new Student("Рублев", Person.Type.STUDENT, 18, Person.Gender.MALE,
            "Группа 1/2021", 1, List.of("Математика", "Физика", "Химия")),
        new Student("Карацев", Person.Type.STUDENT, 17, Person.Gender.MALE,
            "Группа 1/2020", 2, List.of("Программирование на Java", "Основы программирования")),
        new Student("Хачанов", Person.Type.STUDENT, 17, Person.Gender.MALE,
            "Группа 1/2020", 2, List.of("Программирование на C++", "Программирование на Паскале"))
    );
}
```

Поскольку классы `Teacher` и `Student` унаследованы от `Person, List<Person>` может содержать объекты обеих дочерних классов.
При обработке потока необходимо получить список групп:

```
public class TestUniversity {
    public static void main(String... args) {

        people.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getType().equals(Person.Type.PROFESSOR))
//            .map(person -> person.)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

В строке, помеченной комментарием, я хочу вызвать метод `getGroups()`,
но он оказывается недоступным.
Если создать отдельные списки `List<Teacher>` и `List<Student>`, то все работает.
Но меня интересует именно возможность обработки потоков, содержащих разные объекты (но имеющие общего предка, т.е. они не совсем уж разные).

Возможно ли это в принципе? И если возможно, то как это реализовать?

В примере сделана попытка предварительно отфильтровать поток и хотя после фильтрации в потоке должны остаться только объекты типа `Teacher`, все равно метод `getGroups()` недоступен.

Comment: Обрабатывать объекты с общим предком можно только по общим методам. И вам не нужен тип. У вас же разные классы

Answer (score 1):

В данной объектной модели поле типа должно скорее всего быть финальным (без сеттера) и устанавливаться при создании экземпляров конкретных дочерних классов, иначе ничто не запрещает создать экземпляр `Teacher` с типом `Person.Type.STUDENT` и наоборот.

Теперь, если можно быть уверенным, что `Person.Type.PROFESSOR` соответствует классу `Teacher`, можно отфильтровать преподавателей и привести к их типу используя ссылку на метод класса [`Teacher.class::cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-):

```java
people.stream() // Stream<Person>
      .filter(p -> Person.Type.PROFESSOR == p.getType()) // для енумов не нужен equals
      .map(Teacher.class::cast) // Stream<Teacher>
      .map(Teacher::getGroups)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Также  существует аналог `instanceof` [`Class::isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-):

```java
people.stream() // Stream<Person>
      .filter(Teacher.class::isInstance)
      .map(Teacher.class::cast) // Stream<Teacher>
      .map(Teacher::getGroups)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы хоть и отфильтровали, но это только вы знаете о том, что у вас в том списке только объекты типа `Teacher` остались, компилятор об этом не знает никак. Нужно сделать явное приведение типа:

```
people.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getType().equals(Person.Type.PROFESSOR))
    .map(person -> ((Teacher)person).getGroups())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Но лучше будет вообще избавиться от явного поля тип и проверять сразу тип объекта:

```
people.stream()
    .map(p -> (p instanceof Teacher) ? (Teacher) p : null)
    .filter(t -> t != null)
    .map(t -> t.getGroups())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Да, Вы правы! Явное приведение типа помогло!